# Why was @media query discovered so late for responsive web when it has been around since like IE9?

Tags: responsive-design

I've an interesting question. @media query has been around for over 10+ years since IE9 and earlier, however responsive design has been around for just a few years.

Does anyone know why did it take so long for the web to start using @media query? Also does anyone know who are founders or discoverers of @media query usage for responsive design?

Comment: I'm guessing people will downvote you for this .. but I think it's a good question.. perhaps better asked on Quora

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP. Any ideas who were the first to publicize media query and who were early adopters and how it caught on?

Answer (score 2):

For the history of the concept, we can go back to [the earliest draft W3C publishes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-mediaqueries-20010404/), which dates to 4th April 2001, and was authored by Håkon Wium Lie of Opera Software and Tantek Çelik of Microsoft Corporation. The first of these authors was apparently the author of [the very first CSS proposal](http://www.w3.org/People/howcome/p/cascade.html) way back in 1994, which already included the idea of varying styles based on the user's screen size.

Other than the buzzword "responsive", there wasn't really much more to "discover", but W3C standards move *slowly*, and despite Microsoft's involvement in designing it, [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) the first version to support it was IE9, released March 2011 - that's a gap of nearly 10 years! The standard itself [reached Recommendation status only in 2012](http://www.w3.org/standards/history/css3-mediaqueries).

According to [Wikipedia's article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) (I haven't followed up all the references), the term "responsive" was coined in 2010 by Ethan Marcotte. Note that that actually *predates* IE9, so rather questions your whole premise.